# checking if checkbox is checked or not using variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a variable where I have stored my checkbox id's but while I am trying to check if the checkbox is selected or not, it's not working fine.

```
   <script>
   function check(){
       var id = "checkbox1.0";
       if($('#' + id).is(':checked')){alert("checked");} 
   }
   </script>
   <body>
    <input type ="checkbox" id = "checkbox1.0">
    <input type ="checkbox" id = "checkbox2.0" onclick="check()">
   </body>
```

Comment: I don't think those are valid IDs. And `$('#checkbox1.0')` definitely won't do what you think.

Comment: no, it's not returning me anything

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check checkbox checked property using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery)

Comment: Basically I want to store my ID's in a variable and then check it, is there any way out

Comment: any reason for using checkbox1.0 as your id???

Comment: @alokverma Don't use reserved keywords/symbols like the period `.` in your control's ID.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to escape the `.` in your id, but you'd better avoid such ids.

```
   var id = "checkbox1\\.0";
```

***[The demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/jkasS/)***